# How do I get the base64 encoder to encode the value of a variable?

Tags: python, base64

I'm writing a basic base64 encoder just to learn.

```
import base64
prompt = (input("Type your message -> ")
bp = int(input("Base 16, 32, or 64? (Type a number) -> "))
if bp == 16:
    encoded = base64.b16encode(b'prompt')
elif bp == 32:
     encoded = base64.b32encode(b'prompt')
elif bp == 64:
    encoded = base64.b64encode(prompt)
print(encoded)
```

When I run the program, it just prints out "prompt" in base 64. How can I get it to print out whatever message I type instead?

Comment: The code, as posted, has syntax error(s).

Comment: Oh, sorry. That's a typo.

Comment: How do you *know* what gets printed is *"prompt" is base 64*?

Comment: when I use the 64 as is I get "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `encode()` to turn the string into a bytes-like object.

```py
import base64
prompt = input("Type your message -> ")
bp = int(input("Base 16, 32, or 64? (Type a number) -> "))
if bp == 16:
    encoded = base64.b16encode(prompt.encode())
elif bp == 32:
     encoded = base64.b32encode(prompt.encode())
elif bp == 64:
    encoded = base64.b64encode(prompt.encode())
print(encoded)
```

Comment: that one worked too

Comment: Do not use instance method like `Class.method(self)` , do `self.method()`

Comment: @azro Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 0):

The `base64.bXXencode` will raise a `TypeError` if you pass it a str, you need bytes version of your text, ie an encoded one

---

Use `str.encode("utf-8")` and call like `b16encode(prompt)`

```
prompt = input("Type your message -> ").encode("utf-8")
bp = int(input("Base 16, 32, or 64? (Type a number) -> "))
if bp == 16:
    encoded = base64.b16encode(prompt)
elif bp == 32:
    encoded = base64.b32encode(prompt)
elif bp == 64:
    encoded = base64.b64encode(prompt)
else:
    raise Exception(f"The value {bp} isn't supported")
print(encoded)
```

Comment: I'll try this out.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: @GabeCodes note the the other answer it a bit less good as the operation is done multiple times and doesn't specify an encoding